# How to make QGIS recognize EPSG:31468?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I have Shapefiles without a CRS (e.g. without `.prj` file).
I would like to set the CRS (`EPSG:31468`) before I pass the Shapefiles.
I tried the following:

1. Setting a `.prj` file manually with the string

   ```properties
   PROJCS["DHDN_3_degree_Gauss_Kruger_zone_4",
       GEOGCS["GCS_DHDN",
           DATUM["D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
               SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]
           ],
           PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
           UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]
       ],
       PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
       PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
       PARAMETER["central_meridian",12],
       PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
       PARAMETER["false_easting",4500000],
       PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
       UNIT["Meter",1]
   ]
   ```
2. Using ogr2ogr

   ```
   ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:31468 -t_srs EPSG:31468 out.shp in.shp
   ```

If I import those shapes into QGIS, QGIS always recognizes CRS `EPSG:2167`.
I have set in QGIS the correct CRS and exported it in a new file. The `.prj` of the new file is identical to that one of the input file.
So what's wrong with my files?!

Answer (score 1):

As an observation, you should only need to use `-a_srs` to override whatever projection the data is in. But that aside, it's a feature/bug in QGIS that it doesn't change the project's CRS when you load new data, you have to specify it manually either by going to `Settings|Project Properties...` and choosing the CRS you want, or right-clicking on your imported layer and select `Set project CRS from layer`.

IMO, it would be nice if QGIS defaulted to a "no CRS" and either prompted you for a CRS when you create a new project, or to automatically set the project's CRS from the first data that's loaded. It might be worth raising a feature request with the dev team, but I think this has been discussed before with the resolution that it should remain as is.

Comment: Ok, I take a_srs. For the main question: No I meant something different: The CRS of the loaded shape/layer is recognized as 2167 (independently of the project CRS) even though it is defined as 31468 with ogr2ogr

Comment: Where does it tell you what the layer's CRS is? On my copy of 1.7.0, I can find out the proj4 string in the layer's metadata, and I can see the EPSG code of the project on the right-hand side of the status bar, but that's it.

Comment: This time I have the newer version: 1.7.4 ;) EPSG code is shown in Layer-Properties>General>Options or if you choose "Set layer CRS" in the context menu of the layer, the layer CRS is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found in qgis help, that .prj are not adequate to determine the exact projection type. QGIS needs additional .qpj-Files with more information.  As I understand, these files are QGIS-specific.